Postgresql: Any benefits of specific lengths of varchar
Are there any optimization benefits (storage/query speed/...) of choosing specific lengths for VARCHAR columns in PostgreSQL? Like, 2^n-1 or something similar?

No. The “type modifier” (value in parentheses) for character varying is just an extra length limit check, and there are no magic numbers that improve performance.
If you want to save a minuscule bit of performance, use text instead. The implementation is the same as for character varying, and skipping the length check will save a few instructions.
